# Loop through array and retrieve values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through an array and then loop through a list.

The issue I am having is for each `<li>` the entire array is being appended, but what I need to happen is index(0) of array gets added to the 1st li, index(1) to the 2nd li and so on.

Code:

```
// Create our test array.
var arrValues = [ "one", "two", "three" ];

// Loop over each value in the array.
$.each(arrValues,function( intIndex, objValue ){
    $("#list span").each(function() {
        $(this).append(objValue);
    });
});
```

current output:

```
<ul id="list">
        <li>Content 1 here<span>onetwothree</span></li>
        <li>Content 2 here<span>onetwothree</span></li>
        <li>Content 3 here<span>onetwothree</span></li>
    </ul>
```

required output:

```
<ul id="list">
        <li>Content 1 here<span>one</span></li>
        <li>Content 2 here<span>two</span></li>
        <li>Content 3 here<span>three</span></li>
    </ul>
```

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Im not familar with your list element; but if you can use a .get(int index) function you would want to keep a count and use that as the index.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
var arrValues = [ "one", "two", "three" ];

$("#list span").each(function(index) {
    $(this).append(arrValues[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be an easier way to implement:

```
    $("#list span").each(function( intIndex, objValue ){
        $(this).append(arrValues[intIndex]);
    });
```

The issue you currently have is you're iterating through the array ( 3 iterations ), and each iteration is looping through the entire number of `<span>`s, and thus a total of 9 iterations.